# XP Remote Desktop not passing save credentials to server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, rdp, terminal-server

I have XP clients whereby I am setting up some remote desktop connections and saving the credentials and shortcut on the desktop. When the user double-clicks the shortcut, the connection is made to the server, however, they are being prompted with the login screen to enter username and password.

The XP clients and the Windows 2003 server are/is on the same LAN/Domain. In the rdp connection I am saving the username as domain\username. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your server has been configured to always prompt for a password.  To check, launch `Administrative Tools --> Terminal Services Configuration`, select `Connections` in the left pane then double-click `RDP-tcp` and go to the `Logon settings` tab and look for the `Always prompt for password` checkbox - if this is ticked, de-select it and apply the changes.